# In Python, How do you iterate through CSS page numbers?

Tags: python, function, selenium-webdriver

I'd like to create a loop to iterate through page numbers for aria- label.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[aria-label="Page 1"').click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[aria-label="Page 2"').click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[aria-label="Page 3"').click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[aria-label="Page 4"').click()
```

I tried creating a while loop, but could not get it to work.

```
x=0
while x<10:
    print(browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[aria-label="Page [x]"'))
    x=x+1
```

Error message received

```
    NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
 NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[aria-label="Page [x]]""}
```

SO far this code below works:

```
for index in range(10):
    selector = f'[aria-label="Page {index}"'
    print(selector)
```

The code above prints

```
[aria-label="Page 0"]
[aria-label="Page 1"]
[aria-label="Page 2"]
[aria-label="Page 3"]
[aria-label="Page 4"]
[aria-label="Page 5"]
[aria-label="Page 6"]
[aria-label="Page 7"]
[aria-label="Page 8"]
[aria-label="Page 9"]
```

Comment: Are you able to update the error message with more detail? I assume that the error message isn't just one line. This would help heaps with the debugging process. Posting the entire message when you run the Python script would help heaps.

Comment: Could you tell me which page you're trying this from? We need the data to reproduce the error.

Comment: One way is to use an f-string.  `f'[aria-label="Page [{x}]"'`

Comment: All of your selectors are missing the terminating square bracket.

Comment: Also note that if you want to use John Gordon's solution, there should be no square brackets around the X, you want your selectors to be `[aria-label="Page 1"]` not `[aria-label="Page [1]"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic Python way to do this would be with a for loop and a format expression:

```py
for index in range(10):
    selector = f'[aria-label="Page {index}"]'
    element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
    # Do whatever you want to 'element' here
```

The `range` function returns an iterable that yields sequential integers from 0 up to the argument passed excusive. If you want to start a different index, pass that as the first argument `range(1, 11)`.

The format string works by substituting a string representation of the expression included in curly braces. Specifically it

1. Evaluates the expression (here, it's just the value `index`
2. Calls the `__format__` method on the result of the expression, here an `int`
3. Since we didn't specify any unusually formats in our f-string, `__format__` basically just calls `__str__` on the value.
4. `__str__` on an int just returns the decimal string representation of an int (e.g. `1.__str__() == '1'`

Comment: Thank you for your help. The code works!